# Number of simple graphs with no vertices of degree 0

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, inclusion-exclusion

*Determine the number of graphs with no vertices of degree 0 on a given $n$-element vertex set V.*

The total number of simple graphs with $n$ vertices is $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$. We want to find the number of graphs with degree 0 and subtract it from the total.

Let $v$ be an arbitrary vertex in V. Let's denote the set  $$A_{v} = \{E \in 2^{\binom{n}{2}}: deg(v) = 0\}$$
It is the set of edge sets (which correspond to graphs) for which the degree of $v$ is 0. 
Let's calculate the size of $A_{v}$:
We discard all edge sets (graphs) in which there are edges that are incident to $v$. For the rest of the $n-1$ vertices we do not care if there any incident or not, thus the total number of such graphs is 
$$|A_{v}| = 2^{\binom{n-1}{2}}$$
Now consider $|A_{u} \cap A_{v}|$, such that $u \neq v$. We discard edges sets (graphs) in which there are edges adjacent to $u$ or to $v$ or both (if there is an edge $u,v$). 
$$|A_{v} \cap A_{u}| = 2^{\binom{n-2}{2}}$$
More generally, if there are $|U|=k$ such vertices with degree zero, the total number of graphs is 
$$|\bigcap_{u \in U}| = 2^{\binom{n-k}{2}}$$
Now, we can apply the inclusion-exclusion formula
$$|\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}| = \sum \limits_{\emptyset \neq U \subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots , n\}} (-1)^{|U| - 1} |\bigcap \limits_{u \in U} A_{u}|$$

$$|\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}| = \sum \limits_{\emptyset \neq U \subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots , n\}} (-1)^{k- 1} 2^{\binom{n-k}{2}}$$

So, the total number is $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ minus $|\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}|$.

Is this line of reasoning correct?

Comment: This is the right idea with a few minor typos. However, you can do better than summing over all subsets. In particular, every subset of size $k$ contributes $2^{\binom{n-k}{2}}$ to the sum. Why not collect all $\binom{n}{k}$ of them into a single term of the form $\binom{n}{k} 2^{\binom{n-k}{2}}$? Then your sum will run from $1$ to $n$ instead of over all subsets. As another improvement to the formula, you can even include the $2^{\binom{n}{k}}$ term as the $0$-th term of the sum.

Comment: One of the typos I refer to is your substitution for $|U|$ going from $(-1)^{|U| - 1}$ to something other than $(-1)^{k-1}$. In your setup, $|U| = k$.

Comment: I fixed that one now, and I will try to make sense of your other comments as well.